# What is the effect of salt and no. of rounds in mkpasswd encryption?

Tags: encryption, hash, salt

I'm currently trying to understand how salting and no. of rounds work using mkpasswd. These are the commands that I have been experimenting around.

```
cp@cp-vm:~/Asg2_Task1b$ time mkpasswd -m sha-512 pAssWo@%d
$6$d7.91BJxU$zuda2MejtPegqkSiSOXvG23GFOrZllFTkWJaNvAvwjuR4TapJ/3yWY4wHGNPoQI3Y7t3C1BrLT6dRW4/hAZBr.

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.000s

cp@cp-vm:~/Asg2_Task1b$ time mkpasswd -m sha-512 pAssWo@%d -R 5000
$6$rounds=5000$QFwSGjWFy$cd04RyOcUe2lG07hTYJPiKdyFXUiTQe7rJ.7a7YTRXoDI3axv9eWjbfjQn/.38Q33VMuhB37.JwFkYPvGbxox/

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.003s

cp@cp-vm:~/Asg2_Task1b$ time mkpasswd -m sha-512 pAssWo@%d -s "00700000"
$6$00700000$SYaQGLh6uVJJqS30Ep/OsmXn4K7LjiE5jYmMENcRg1G03uH8aH6t3mKRbvLOTU58fdjIdE9CZXG7AHyaO.uyV.

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.003s
sys 0m0.000s

cp@cp-vm:~/Asg2_Task1b$ time mkpasswd -m sha-512 pAssWo@%d -s "00700000" -R 4000
$6$rounds=4000$00700000$ntXSoAqnvmOXGLjs5j4lEs9DMuFGceIIZ7r69lqme2YPM8gLMhLBK0/M2YFmyxNdyD29Hs66meDXzOuuzA7XB/

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s

cp@cp-vm:~/Asg2_Task1b$ time mkpasswd -m sha-512 pAssWo@%d -s "00700000" -R 10000
$6$rounds=10000$00700000$wsGRn35/Gjfsj4mXCmOUjRj1reMwGxjQtJShtDJ.Pxyg2vh3OW3JlK8m6XoNhybC/EEugD2QPUT.CZzSBde7z/

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.005s
sys 0m0.000s
```

I want to understand why there is a difference between the time when the salt and no. of rounds are changed because I thought the salt always remains 32-bit. So, why is there a time difference?

If anyone can explain in detail, that would be greatly appreciated as I wish to learn as much as I can.

Thank you! :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because these measurements are unreliable and cannot be used for an actual comparison of whats going on. Running the same commands again and again on my system gives different results, because the actual time depends on what is in the cache, what other activity is going on on the system, power saving of the CPU ... A large part of this time is loading and starting the dynamically linked binary - not the actual different functionality

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I tested too and was surprised to find that going from 1 to 10000 rounds is only 10 more longer. I thought using rounds was a way to slow down brute force attacks, but it looks like it's not that effective? Am I missing something?

Comment: @A.L: Using a generic hash like sha-512 for this is a bad idea in the first place since such hashes are designed to be fast.  Just check `openssl speed sha512` to get an idea how fast this is. Better use something like `-m bcrypt`.

Answer (score 1):

You're overestimating the strength of sha512-crypt. If you look at benchmarks (e. g. [using the hashcat tool on an RTX 4090](https://gist.github.com/Chick3nman/32e662a5bb63bc4f51b847bb422222fd)), you'll see that the algorithm just isn't very effective against brute-force attacks, except maybe with extremely high round counts. In the above mentioned benchmark, an RTX 4090 can calculate almost 1.2 million(!) hashes per second if the round count is 5,000 (the default value). It might be less with the mkpasswd/crypt implementation running on your CPU, but reducing or increasing the round count a bit isn't going to give you any perceivable difference.

There are much stronger password hashing algorithms like Argon2, scrypt or bcrypt. Those do in fact have a noticeable slowdown.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have a few follow-up questions :

1. Are there any other factors besides the password hashing algorithm that affect password security (e.g. password length, complexity, entropy, etc.)?
2. In what scenarios would you recommend using sha512-crypt over the other password hashing algorithms, and vice versa?
3. How do the benchmarks for sha512-crypt compare to the benchmarks for the other password hashing algorithms?

Thank you!

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) Yes, the strength of the password itself is crucial. A good password hashing algorithm can slow down brute force attacks to some extent, but if the password is weak, an attacker still has a chance to guess it. On the other hand, the stronger a password is, the less important it is to have a sophisticated hashing algorithm. 2) I wouldn't recommend sha512-crypt for anything but legacy systems where there's no other choice. 3) You can compare the algorithms yourself using the above link. The lower the rate of hashes per second, the better (roughly speaking).